# How to submit form AND set post variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three buttons in my form. I want to use JS to confirm when clicking the delete button. Upon confirm, the form should be submitted. How do i do that?

This is how far I got:
My form:

```
 <form method="post" id="form1">
 <button id="button1" name="action" type="submit" value="save"></button>
 <button id="button2" name="action" type="submit" value="update"></button>
 <button id="button3" name="action" type="submit" value="delete"></button>
 </form>
```

and a JS (swal) script to confirm before submitting

```
<script>
var formname = "are you sure you want to proceed?";
document.querySelector("#button3").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var form = this;
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  swal({
      
      title: "Delete?",
      text: formname,
      icon: "warning",
      buttons: [
        'Cancel',
        'Yes'
      ],
      dangerMode: true,
    }).then(function(isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {
        document.querySelector("#form1").submit();

      } 
    });
});
```

The confirmation script runs fine, but upon clicking on yes the form is submitted without action=delete..

Answer (score 0):

First try to put type="button" for 'delete'.

(Type Button won't submit form on its own. It is a simple button which is used to perform some operation by using javascript whereas Type Submit is a kind of button which by default submit the form whenever user clicks on submit button)

```
 <button id="button3" name="action" type="button" click="deleteFormData()" value="delete"></button>

function deleteFormData(){

// write the delete action here

}
```